# Converting time series transaction data into an occurrence count table of all products in R

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, sqldf

I have 5 million+ rows of daily transactions data in a column format of (year, month, day of the month, hour of the day, product that is purchased):
I created this data frame as an example *(please note that the original data is not ordered as I have given in this example and the range of date spreads over a span of 4 years.)*:

[image]

```
all_product_names = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")
my_table <- data.frame(year = c(2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022),
           month = c(rep(4,12)),
           day = c(rep(3,12)),
           hour = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2),
           product_name = c("a","b","c","a","c","c","d","f","a","b","c","f") )
```

My desired output is a table where for a given **time instance** (a specific combination of year-month-day-hour) count of all product purchases are extended into the table as columns. "all_product_names" variable gives you a list of all the products that exist. Notice that not every **time instance** has all products purchased, for those instances, the "count table" value for that product must be zero. Here is what I am trying to get my output grouping to look like:

[image]

Using sqldf I have tried to group by product so that I get the count of product_name for every **time instance**, however It does not count into account of products that do not exist for every instance. And also I need to convert the row format into columns as indicated above in the solution table example.

```
xx <-sqldf('SELECT year,month,day,hour,product_name,COUNT(product_name) FROM my_table GROUP BY product_name,hour,day,month,year
      ORDER BY product_name ASC')
```

Also as a note I do not have to use sqldf library. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the output to include columns like g/h/i which may not (in this case are not) present in the source data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
my_table %>%
  count(year, month, day, hour, product_name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = product_name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: I cant believe the solution is this short and easy. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Am I wrong if I say the result is different from the expected output? some columns are missing after pivoting (columns g to i).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(my_table) # if not yet a data.table

results <- dcast(my_table, year + month + day + hour ~ product_name, fun.aggregate = length)

results[, setdiff(all_product_names, my_table$product_name) := 0L]
setcolorder(results, c(names(my_table)[1:4], all_product_names))


results
#    year month day hour a b c d e f g h i
# 1: 2022     4   3    0 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 2: 2022     4   3    1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
# 3: 2022     4   3    2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Because `fun.aggregate=length`, there is no need to specify `fill=0` because it will be 0 anyway for non-existing combinations. Also, I think that the result is slightly different from the expected output. you might consider adding something like `result[, setdiff(all_product_names, my_table$product_name) := 0L]` to your current result; but let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: valid suggestion, I added the code to get the complete OP's desired result